# Show that $|\alpha'(t)|^2-1=0$ for any arbitrary parameter $t$

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

There is this supposed to be not so hard question but concept of re-parametrisation by arc length bothers me a bit.

Let $\alpha:I\to R^2$ be a regular paramatrised plane curve (arbitrary parameter) and let $n(t)$ be its normal vector.

I was trying to show that $$\langle\alpha'(t)-\frac{k'(t)}{k(t)^2}n(t)+\frac{1}{k(t)}n'(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle=0$$

My approach:

$\langle\alpha'(t)-\frac{k'(t)}{k(t)^2}n(t)+\frac{1}{k(t)}n'(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle=\alpha'(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)-\frac{k'(t)}{k(t)^2}n(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)+\frac{1}{k(t)}n'(t)\cdot\alpha'(t)$

$=|\alpha'(t)|^2-\frac{1}{k(t)}k(t)n(t)\cdot n(t)$

$=|\alpha'(t)|^2-1$

And it will equal to 0 if the curve is parametrised by arc length.

My questions are:
1. Do we have to reparametrise the curve by arc length in the first place?  If so, how should we do that?
2. If we did not need to reparametrise the curve by arc length, how can we say that $|\alpha'(t)|^2-1=0$?

I think this problem is almost done but just that one last step. Can anyone please clarify it?

Helps are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

I just realised it is related to this question

[Tangent of evolute and singed curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936406/tangent-of-evolute-and-singed-curvature/936414#936414)

But I am still unable to show the last step! Thanks.